# ImportError: No module named my_project.wsgi error with foreman start

Tags: django, heroku

I am trying to push my project into heroku and I am following these instructions:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django

I am currently stuck on the part the says `foreman start`

I get this error: --> full error http://dpaste.com/3Y213Y2

```
(boothie.0.1)MTVL1289dd026:HerokuBoothie bli1$ foreman start
14:59:05 web.1  | started with pid 58353
14:59:05 web.1  | [2014-12-09 14:59:05 -0800] [58353] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.1.1
14:59:05 web.1  | [2014-12-09 14:59:05 -0800] [58353] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (58353)
14:59:05 web.1  | [2014-12-09 14:59:05 -0800] [58353] [INFO] Using worker: sync
14:59:05 web.1  | [2014-12-09 14:59:05 -0800] [58356] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 58356
14:59:05 web.1  | [2014-12-09 14:59:05 -0800] [58356] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
14:59:05 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
14:59:05 web.1  |   File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/HerokuBoothie/boothie.0.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
14:59:05 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
14:59:05 web.1  |   File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/HerokuBoothie/boothie.0.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 114, in init_process
14:59:05 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
14:59:05 web.1  |   File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/HerokuBoothie/boothie.0.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi
14:59:05 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
14:59:05 web.1  |   File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/HerokuBoothie/boothie.0.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
14:59:05 web.1  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
14:59:05 web.1  |   File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/HerokuBoothie/boothie.0.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
14:59:05 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
14:59:05 web.1  |   File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/HerokuBoothie/boothie.0.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app
14:59:05 web.1  |     __import__(module)
14:59:05 web.1  | ImportError: No module named HerokuBoothie.wsgi
```

Here is a picture of my project structure. The project is located inside a directory called `HerokuBoothie`.
[image]

Profile:

`web: gunicorn HerokuBoothie.wsgi --log-file -`

Answer (score 2):

I think it's caused by your project structure; if you follow the heroku tutorial onto the point you have error (`foreman start` part), your directory structure would look like this:

```
hellodjango/
    manage.py
    Procfile
    hellodjango/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    venv/
        bin/
        include/
        lib/
```

You can see the structure you have is a bit different, there's an additional `HerokuBoothie` directory in your structure. I think restructure your project (something like `mv ~/Development/Django/HerokuBoothie/HerokuBoothie/* ~/Development/Django/HerokuBoothie` and remove the empty `HerokuBoothie` dir) would solve this issue, but you might have to change some codes if you use absolute paths in your codes.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the `pythonpath` as your `HerokuBoothie` module is located in another folder:

```
web: gunicorn HerokuBoothie.wsgi --pythonpath ../HerokuBoothie --log-file -
```